# In JavaScript is there an equivelant to Python's "try ... except" feature?

Tags: javascript

Here is the Python code that I am trying to solve this problem in JavaScript:

```
try:
    float(s) if '.' in s else int(s)
    return True
except ValueError:
    return False
```

I'm looking for the keyword equivalent to "except" in Python.

Comment: Did you bother looking at the documentation of Javascript's `try` statement? It would have told you exactly what you needed to know.

Comment: I've improved the grammar and made the title clearer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Try/Catch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120693/javascript-try-catch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, we have `try`, `catch` and `finally`.

```
try {
   //may throw
} catch(ex) {
   //handle the error, where ex or what ever you choose to call it is your exception reference
} finally {
   //perform this code regardless
}
```